# running javascript in an asp page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to be able to run some basic javascript client-side within an asp page, so as a test I have this:

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function TestClick() { alert("here");}
   </script>
</head>

<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <button onclick="TestClick()">Click Me</button>
   </form>
</body>
```

But when I run this I get the error:

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'TestClick' is undefined

I must be doing something stupid here...

Comment: Might have something to do with the `runat="server"`, since the server doesn't have that function. JS-wise, it's working, so it's an asp issue.

Comment: If I remove the `runat="server"` from `form1` then the page errors.

Comment: You could remove the runat server and manually POST the for to the server i guess. What is the TestClick function going to do?

Comment: It's going to do a window.postMessage which I don't think I can do in asp code

Comment: Well, it works as it should in a normal aspx page. Are you sure the error is not generated somewhere else?